# How to set message priority using TOS?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

The IP header has type of service (TOS) field. It can be used to set for Classful Queueing Disciplines, i.e. PRIO.

I have tested the following codes.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int listenfd, connfd, optval;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
   socklen_t clilen;
   pid_t     childpid;
   char      mesg[16];

   listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   bzero(mesg, 0, sizeof(mesg));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port = htons(32000);
   bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   listen(listenfd, 1024);

   for (;;)
   {
      clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
      connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &clilen);

      if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
      {
         close(listenfd);

         for (;;)
         {
            optval = 0x28;
            setsockopt(cliaddr, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, &optval, sizeof(optval));
            strcpy(mesg, "tos=0x28");
            sendto(connfd, mesg, sizeof(mesg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
            sleep(2);

            optval = 0x58;
            strcpy(mesg, "tos=0x58");
            setsockopt(cliaddr, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, &optval, sizeof(optval));
            sendto(connfd, mesg, sizeof(mesg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
            sleep(2);
         }

      }

      close(connfd);
   }
}
```

The packets can be sent with TOS field set successfully. But what shall I do to make message priority take effect? Thanks!

Comment: you should setup with tc your machine to make sure that 0x28 gets higher priority on the egress queue.

Answer (score 2):

One important feature of the TOS field is that routers along the way can prioritize the packet based on the TOS field.

Another important effect of using the TOS field is within the local machine. For example, in the Linux kernel the network lawyer has something called [Traffic Control](http://wiki.linuxwall.info/doku.php/en:ressources:dossiers:networking:traffic_control) which throttles or reorders outgoing IP traffic. The default behavior on [Linux 2.2+](http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt) is something called a *pfifo_fast* which contains three separate queues (or bands) for outgoing traffic. Each queue being a higher priority than the next, meaning all traffic from queue 0 is pushed out before anything from queue 1 is pushed out to the network. The TOS field is what determines which of the queues an outgoing IP packet will be placed in. For more info, look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-pfifo_fast). Be careful playing with the TC feature, you can easily cripple a computer. I suggest using a VM.

I am not sure if this behavior exists with non-Linux platforms.

Answer (score 1):

TOS is an instruction to a router. It has no effect unless all the routers in the path agree on what it means, pass it on to the next router intact, and do something about it themselves. Do they? And if there are no routers in the path it has no effect at all.

Comment: Thank you, EJP. But Linux has traffic control (tc) tool to queue and filter packets. I read a paper which uses tos field to make priority assignment.

Comment: @allenchen Of course it does, that's what TOS is for. By 'routers' I should also have included network-bridging hosts of course.